# Python фреймворк Kivy не видит файл с расширением .kv

Tags: python, kivy

Проблема такова. Определяю родительский и дочерний классы в файле main.py. Также определяю дочерний класс в файле my.kv, добавляя к нему 2 виджета (Label и Button).

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 

class MyApp(App):
    pass

class Child(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Parent(BoxLayout):

    obj = ObjectProperty(Child())

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.obj)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
Parent:

<Child>:
    Label:
        text: "Some text"
    Button:
        text: "Button"
```

Определяю дочерний класс как свойство для родительского класса и при инициализации добавляю его в родительский. Но при запуске я не вижу ранее добавленных виджетов (Label и Button), на экране просто пустой виджет. Как будто файл my.kv просто игнорируется. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: А не нужно ли в `.py` указывать где-нибудь `my.kv`?

Comment: Нет. Он должен подхватываться на автомате. Так как его название совпадает с классом-приложением в нижнем регистре и без "App".

Answer (score 0):

В классе приложения нужно реализовать метод `build`, откуда нужно вернуть объект класса `Child` (в вашем случае):

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Child()


class Child(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Parent(BoxLayout):

    obj = ObjectProperty(Child())

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Если использовать метод build, то в моем случае он должен возвращать именно экземпляр класса Parent, а не Child. А экземпляр класса Child должен быть как kivy свойство для экземпляра Parent, чтобы я мог удалять его из экземпляра Parent и добавлять когда мне нужно. Это работает со встроенными виджетами. Но почему-то не работает с виджетом, определенном в kivy language файле my.kv

Comment: @Vladimir, мне кажется в вашем случае стоит попробовать грузить kv файл явно по имени.